# Internal energy at constant entropy and volume is less than zero - Explanation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy, education

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srjNMMtPATo&list=PLTp4B-jXB5mr5dmSfwenrAozVLxu_L_iX&index=119&t=0s) MIT videolecture (minute 4.12) where there is the relationship:

$$ \left( dU \right)_{S,V} < 0 $$

which states that the internal energy, at constant entropy and volume, is less than zero.

Why? I know that:

$$ T \, dS = dU + P \, dV $$

so, if $ dS=dV=0 $, I get $ dU=0 $.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a bit more context, so that people don't need to watch a 4 minute video to be able to answer. What is the video about?

Comment: Hello @BySymmetry, the video is about a basic course on thermodynamics and the goal of the videolecture is the understand when a process is spontaneous.

Comment: I started watching the video. When it got to the point where he started talking about property changes holding others constant he referred to an isolated system. That raised a red flag to me because there can be no change in internal energy of an isolated system, whether or not changes are spontaneous. That’s when I stopped watching.

Comment: The equation you wrote is valid only if no reaction is occurring.  Otherwise, U also changes when the number of moles of the various species changes.

Comment: Hello @ChetMiller, if the volume and the entropy are constant, and if the number of moles of the various species change, how does the relashionship change?

Comment: There is an additional term equal to the sum of the chemical potentials of the various species times the change in their number of moles.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification @ChetMiller.

Comment: @ChetMiller By any chance did you look at the video? If so, what did you think of it? Regarding the OPs equation, if there are no chemical reactions involved, and no change in entropy and volume, seems to me $\Delta U$=0.

Comment: @BobD Yes, I saw part of the video, but didn't want to spend time watching much of it.  To say that I had major issues with how this was approached in the video would be putting it mildly.  But to discuss this would require more space than is provided here.  If you like, we can continue at our alternate site, in a private conversation.

Comment: @ChetMiller I had major issues with it also. As I commented earlier, when the lecturer referred to the system being isolated and then went on to say there is a change in internal energy (for an isolated system) I glazed over. I don't think its worth our time to analyze the lecture. What does disappoint me is this isn't the first time I found the MIT on line course lacking.

Comment: @ChetMiller And one more thing. Do you agree with the accepted answer? If you prefer not to opine on it here, I understand.

Comment: @BobD No, I do prefer not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take system in thermal equilibrium with its surroundings at temperature T. When change in the system occurs and there is a transfer of energy as heat between the system and the surroundings the Clausius inequality ($dS \ge dq/T$) reads:

$dS - \frac{dq}{T} \ge 0$

At constant volume i.e. in the absence of non-expansion work, $dq_V = dU$ consequently

$dS - \frac{dU}{T} \ge 0$

that can be rewritten as

$TdS \ge dU$

At constant entropy the expression becomes

$dU_{S,V} \le 0$

This relation states that if the entropy and volume of the system are constant, then the internal energy must decrease in a spontaneous change.
If the entropy of the system in unchanged during a transformation then there must be an increase in the entropy of the surroundings, which can be achieved by a transfer of heat.

Comment: Did you watch the video?

Comment: Hello @gioretikto; thank you for your explanation.